# Different Types of Hosting WCF application and there advantages

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-hosting, wcf-http

There are different types of Hosting can be done.

1. windows process activation services (WAS)
2. IIS
3. Self hosting
4. Hosting in a Windows service

is there advantage of using one over another? which one is preferable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730158.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx) can help. But basically:

1) IIS now using WAS

2) IIS hosting. Pros: generally no hosting code required, easy to maintain, IIS infrastructure (security, sessions, site integration etc). Cons: 'passive' services, require IIS.

3) Self hosting. Pros: easy debugging. Cons: no infrastructure, req. custom hosting code, interactive usage (generally speaking).

4) Hosting in a Windows service. Pros: for 'active', long running services, services infrastructure (start/stop/pause, unattended (non interactive) execution, dependencies, mmc etc), relatively easy to manage. Cons: req. custom hosting code, relatively hard to debug (vs IIS hosting).